# Speeding up remote connection

Tags: networking, vpn, nas

I've got a network setup at home. I've got a NAS(unraid), a few pc's and a few raspberrys at home. Recently my brother moved out and he would like to connect to our video's and stuff on the NAS from his home with his raspberry2 (kodi installed).

```
Home       ------------Internet------------  Brothers home

*192.168.0.5 (Nas)                           *192.168.100.255(router)
*192.168.0.31(VPN raspberry)                 *192.168.100.25 (kodi raspberry pi 2)
*192.168.0.1 (router)
```

Now ive managed to create a VPN which connects his RPi2(kodi) to our network via a RPi2(VPN) in our network. But the problem is, currently he can only watch SD content without stuttering etc.

The VPN raspberry also has an open vpn program installed to keep my public ip updated.

Oh and all these connections are wired connections. So my question is, do you guys know a way to speed up this connection, maybe by using an alternative to VPN or whatever.

Comment: Which raspberry pi are you using (1,2,3) and model? The first ones are rather slow. What's your internet bandwidth?

Comment: both raspberrys are model B2, my upload speed is 41Mbps (according to speedtest.net)

Comment: This sounds like a bandwidth problem

Comment: Are you sure? my initial thought was that maybe the VPN had too much overhead or something. Do you know a way to test this?